# for element contain null in java

Tags: java, for-loop, null

Here some sudo code that I want to do.

```
String[] listA = new String { "a1", "a2"}
String[] listB = new String { null}
String[] listC = new String { "c1", "c2"}

for( String a : listA) {
  for( String b : listB) {
    for( String c : listC) {
       if( a!=null) System.out.print( a);
       System.out.print(",");
       if( b!=null) System.out.print(b);
       System.out.print(",");
       if( c!=null) System.out.print(c);
       System.out.println("");
    }
  }
}
```

My expect result is

```
a1,,c1
a1,,c2
a2,,c1
a2,,c2
```

But since listB is null, code logic cannot get into print. I tried condition to check list and make all possibility of logic like below.

```
if( listA != null) {
  for( String a : list A) {
     if( listB !=null) {
        for(String b : listB) {
           if( listC != null) {
           }
           else { 
                ...
           }
        }
     }
     else {
          ....
     }
  }
}
else {
    ...... similar code in here
}
```

I don't think it's best way to solve this problem. Any idea of this?

Comment: Maybe you should put some real Java code in the question.

Comment: As it is now, your program doesn't work because `print a` and `print ","` are not valid.

Comment: changed print code as real java code.

Comment: Well then what you have now should work. What's the problem?

Comment: Once you fix the compilation problems in the array declarations by adding [] (e.g. `String[] listA = new String[] { "a1", "a2"};`), your code works as expected.

Comment: @J.Done Why would you use nested loop when your arrays are not contained within the one another?

Comment: There was differnce between String[] listB = new String { null};  and String[] listB = null; never mind. I better to use first one.

Comment: SELF SOLVED. THANKS EVERYONE :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called the ['product'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of three sets (lists).  But with the twist that when either of the lists is empty, it will be replaced by a set with an 'empty element' in it.

```
// pseudo code
String[] safeList(String[] list) { if list.length == 0 return {''} else return list; }

// carthesian product with a twist
static void safeProductWithATwist(
    String[] listA, String[] listB, String[] listC) {
    for(String a: safeList(listA)) 
      for(String b: safeList(listB)) 
        for(String c: safeList(listC)) 
          foo(a, b, c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong in java

```
String[] listA = new String { "a1", "a2"}
String[] listB = new String { null}
String[] listC = new String { "c1", "c2"}
```

Try this one. This will work for you.

```
public class prac {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] listA = {"a1","a2"};
        String[] listB = {null};
        String[] listC = {"c1", "c2"};

for( String a : listA) {
  for( String b : listB) {
    for( String c : listC) {
       if( a!=null) System.out.print( a);
       System.out.print(",");
       if( b!=null) System.out.print(b);
       System.out.print(",");
       if( c!=null) System.out.print(c);
       System.out.println("");
    }
  }
}

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package Test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] listA =  { "a1", "a2"};
        String[] listB =  { null};
        String[] listC = { "c1", "c2"};
        int count = 0;

        for( String a : listA) { //Two time it will enter

          for( String b : listB) {
              count++;
              System.out.println("");
              System.out.println("Count"+count);
              System.out.println("");
            for( String c : listC) {
                System.out.println("");
               if( a!=null)  System.out.print(a);
               System.out.print(",");
               if( b!=null) System.out.print( b);
               System.out.print(",");
               if( c!=null) System.out.print(a);
            }
          }
        }
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Count1


a1,,a1
a1,,a1
Count2


a2,,a2
a2,,a2
```

It will enter into loop, because **`null`** is an element in **listB**.
So it will not print b,because you are checking for `b!=null`.
And in the answer few mistakes in the code also corrected.